# How to add/remove codecs in linux

Tags: linux, kernel, codec, mplayer, filesystems

Friends,

I'm new to Linux, I need to work on Linux. I have ported Linux to AT91SAM9261-EK board. Now i need to work on Codecs. I just know the definition of codec from wikipedia, Now i need add my own codec to the board.

I want to know,

1. Where codec will be preset in 1)File System, 2)Kernel or 3)Player
2. And how to add codec while building entire source, please tell me the steps i need follow.
3. And also how to remove the codec.
4. How to play the video files from pendrive in console, now i can play audio by command

   'mplayer "filename" '. Don't know how to play video.

Please help me, How to do this.

**Edit: Added information posted by asker as an answer: -*DMA57361*.**

I'm Getting following error while playing Video.

```
It Seems there is no Xvideo support for your video card available.
Opening Video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
Selscted video codec: [ffodivx] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-4)
Forced Audio codec :MAD
Opening audio decoder: [faad] AAC (MPEG2/4 Advanced Audio Coding)
Selected audio codec:[faad]
X server image format not supported, Please contact the developers
FATAL: Cannot initialise video driver
FATAL: Could not  initialise video filters

Exiting.... (End of File)
```

What it means, Any help.

Answer (score 1):

All of the codecs you need are included with the [`mplayer` source code](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html).  There is a [complete list of the ones included](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/info.html) on their website.

Answer (score 1):

> Where codec will be preset in 1)File
>   System, 2)Kernel or 3)Player

On Linux, there is no central place for codecs. Codecs are built into individual media applications/players. Sometimes, the applications will use a codec packages as a shared library (`.so`), in that case several applications can share a codec, but each individual app still needs support for the codec built-in.

> And how to add codec while building
>   entire source, please tell me the
>   steps i need follow.
>   And also how to remove the codec.

This depends on the individual application.

> How to play the video files from
>   pendrive in console, now i can play
>   audio by command
>
> 'mplayer "filename" '. Don't know how
>   to play video.

Actually, exactly the same : `mplayer video.avi`.

If this does not work, it can be for any number of reasons, one of which is a missing codec.

MPlayer supports loads of codecs, however it can be configured at compile-time to not include all of them. So depending on how your version of MPlayer was compiled, a particular codec may be missing.

If you still have problems, please update your question with the exact error message you are getting, then we'll probably be able to help.

**Edit:**

Looking at the error messages you posted, the problem is not at all with the codecs, but with the video card.

> It Seems there is no Xvideo support
>   for your video card available.

MPlayer tries to use the [X Video extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_video_extension) to display the video. This fails, probably because your video card and/or driver do not support it. This in itself is not fatal, MPlayer automatically falls back to plain X.

> X server image format not supported,
>   Please contact the developers

This is a general message meaning that the video could not be displayed due to problems with video setup. This is probably an incompatibility between your video card / driver / video settings and MPlayer. I don't know enough to help here, sorry.

What video card and driver do you use? You could try posting on the [MPlayer mailing list](https://lists.mplayerhq.hu/mailman/listinfo/mplayer-users) to ask for help.

Comment: Hi, sleske Thanks for your reply                                   It Seems there is no Xvideo support for your video card available.
Opening Video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
Selscted video codec: [ffodivx] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-4)
Forced Audio codec :MAD
Opening audio decoder: [faad] AAC (MPEG2/4 Advanced Audio Coding)
Selected audio codec:[faad]
X server image format not supported, Please contact the developers
FATAL: Cannot initialise video driver
FATAL: Could not  initialise video filters

Exiting.... (End of File)

Comment: Hi,this is the errot                                                         It Seems there is no Xvideo support for your video card available.
Opening Video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
Selscted video codec: [ffodivx] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-4)
Forced Audio codec :MAD
Opening audio decoder: [faad] AAC (MPEG2/4 Advanced Audio Coding)
Selected audio codec:[faad]
X server image format not supported, Please contact the developers
FATAL: Cannot initialise video driver
FATAL: Could not  initialise video filters

Exiting.... (End of File)